# verilog counter not starting from 0

Tags: verilog, counter, simulation

I'm using this counter as a mux select pins and I need it to start from 0, but in simulation in the first cycle it is starting from 1 and at the next cycle it starts from 0.

```
module upcounter(clk,reset,out);
input clk,reset;
output reg [2 : 0]out = 3'b000;


always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
if(reset)
  out <= 3'b000;
else 
  out <= out + 3'b001;
end
endmodule
```

[image: This is the simulation waves]

This is my testbench codes:

```
module counter_tst;
reg clk;
wire [2 : 0] out;
reg rst;

upcounter u0(clk,rst,out);

initial
   clk = 1'b1;
always
#1 clk = ~clk;

initial
begin
   rst=0;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: @Md.shah how do you know that it does not? where is your test bench? There is nothing wrong with the code you published. No need to initialize 'out' in declaration.

Comment: @serge I have added the simulation waves.

Comment: @ToTamire I dont think it will be effective in solving my problem.

Comment: @ToTamire Here you are.

Answer (score -1):

As @Serge says the test bench is important to explain what you are seeing.

Your testbench only ever sets `rst` to `0`, so we can safely ignore the code that is conditioned on `reset` entirely. No positive edges or values of `1` to worry about.

At time `0` your testbench forces `clk` to `1`. This is treated as a positive edge, as such immediately after that `out` is incremented to `1`. Since you don't have a `<= #n` delay when you increment `out` it appears to take effect immediately. With this sort of thing, I find including simulation delays helps debugging.

Consider this version of the code and testbench. I've slowed down the clock ticking by a factor of 10, and inserted a `#1` delay in the `out` value incrementing. I've also removed all the orphaned `rst`/`reset` code to focus on the effect you are seeing:

```
// code.v
module upcounter(clk,out);
   input clk;
   output reg [2 : 0] out = 3'b000;

   always @(posedge clk)
     out <= #1 out + 3'b001;

endmodule

module counter_tst;
   reg clk;
   wire [2 : 0] out;

   upcounter u0(clk,out);

   initial
     begin
       clk = 1'b1;
       $monitor("time = %0d", $time, " clk = %b out = %d", clk, out);
       $dumpvars();
       #1000 $finish();
     end

   always
     #10 clk = ~clk;

endmodule
```

Compile and run it as follows:

```
$ iverilog code.v
$ ./a.out
VCD info: dumpfile dump.vcd opened for output.
time = 0 clk = 1 out = 0
time = 1 clk = 1 out = 1
time = 10 clk = 0 out = 1
time = 20 clk = 1 out = 1
time = 21 clk = 1 out = 2
time = 30 clk = 0 out = 2
time = 40 clk = 1 out = 2
time = 41 clk = 1 out = 3
< etc >
```

You should now be able to see that the first increment to `out` is happening because of the observed `posedge clk`.